# Spam comes from Google Searches

Tags: gmail, google-search

I have been getting a LOT of spam on gmail after I do a Google search.  For example, I did a search for a government facility called HARPP.  After that, I'm suddenly getting a bunch of spam for products of that name or similar.

Does Google send my searches out for people to find?

Comment: Maybe you should do a malware scan on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Might be. But you can clear your Google web history and turn it off also if you want.

See: https://history.google.com/history/settings